# Access my token while keeping it secret (omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth to link API with users. Currently I have my site's token and secret in the `omniauth.rb` file. How can I grab that data for API `GET` requests? If I can't, where should I store it and how should I retrieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're not familiar with OAuth itself. In order to implement your API interactions effectively, I advise you to read [Beginner's Guide to OAuth](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/).

Basically, you're going to register your *consumer* application in *provider* application. During that process, you will obtain a secret token, associated with your *consumer* app. Using that token to identify your *consumer* application, *provider* will generate *access token* for each subsequent request. These tokens are short-lived and basically allow only *one* requrest to API.